# Javascript unwanted "empty" property after merging objects

Tags: javascript

I want to merge objects based on a property, and I want to use this property as the key for the merged array.
here is my code:

```
 let mergedProfiles = [];
  for (let set of profiles) {
      if (Object.keys(mergedProfiles).indexOf(String(set.profile_id)) >= 0) { // if profile id exists
          mergedProfiles[set.profile_id].push(set);
      } else {
          mergedProfiles[set.profile_id] = [];
          mergedProfiles[set.profile_id].push(set);
      }
  }
```

example of profile object: `{user_id: 17, name: "test", country: "US", bid: 0.02, profile_id: "1", user_id: 12}`

the merge is working fine but for some reason I cant understand I always end up with `empty` as my first property in the `mergedProfiles`, any idea what am Imissing?

Comment: why is `mergedProfiles` an array? You seem to be using it as a lookup table

Comment: Please edit your code, click `<>` and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object instead of an array, because you get a sparse array with not used indices.

```js
var profiles = [{ user_id: 17, name: "test", country: "US", bid: 0.02, profile_id: "1", user_id: 12 }],
    mergedProfiles = {},
    s;

for (s of profiles) {
    if (!mergedProfiles[s.profile_id]) {
        mergedProfiles[s.profile_id] = [];
    }
    mergedProfiles[s.profile_id].push(s);
}

console.log(mergedProfiles);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store the results in an object so you can reference by key.

```
const allProfiles = {};
for(let set of profiles) {
    if(typeof allProfiles[set.profile_id] === "undefined") {
        allProfiles[set.profile_id] = [set];
    }
    else {
        allProfiles[set.profile_id].push(set);
    }
}
```

The reason your first element is empty is that you are declaring an empty JavaScript array and then failing to initialize all of the elements.

If you do something like

```
var someArray = [];
someArray[5] = 10;
console.log(someArray); // [empty × 5, 5]
```

then the result is a sparse array where the first 5 elements (0 - 4) are all empty or in other words `undefined`. In your example you are doing the same as above where your profile_id is some integer greater than 0.